# react exporting and importing components

Tags: reactjs

I was going through a codebase and this is what I see there.

Basically they have created a component in another file, say CheckIn
and they create a CheckIn component in that file and export it like this

```
module.exports = CheckIn
```

and after that in the index file they are again importing it and exporting it.

```
import CheckIn from './components/CheckIn';

export default CheckIn;
```

what kind of exporting is this? and why is this needed/used?

EDITED to add one more thing which is quite similar , would appreciate an explanation for the below code too. is the View being exported below also have the scss styles exported with it??
I have also seen something like this:-

```
import PageView from './components/View';
import './view.scss';

export default View;
```

so, how does that work?

Comment: Sometimes devs import many component/class in another (let call this superImporter) component/class. When this superImporter is imported somewhere in your code, all the other class also gets imported (possibly also doing some kind of initialization also). Though this technique is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common practice to re export all the files in folder using `index.js`. When you `import` without specifying file name but only specify folder name then `import` will try to find `index.js` file in that directory and will import `index.js`.Suppose you have following directory structure

```
\-- component
    \-- checkin.js
    \-- index.js
\-- someFile.js
```

If you want to import `checkin.js` file in `someFile.js` then you would write

```
import Checkin from "./component/checkin"
```

But if you are re-exporting the `checkin` in `index.js` file as you mentioned in the question, then you won't have to specify the file name and you can directly import the file in `someFile.js` like this

```
import Checkin from "./component"
```

This will look for `index.js` file in `component` folder and will `import` that.

Also if there are multiple files in a directory

```
\-- component
    \-- A.js
    \-- B.js
    \-- C.js
    \-- index.js
\-- someFile.js
```

Then you can export all of them in `index.js` file

```
// index.js
export A from './A';
export B from './B';
export C from './C';
```

And then in `someFile.js` you can import them like this

```
import {A, B, C} from "./component"
```

Comment: aha! so, we are actually exporting it from index.js without having to import them? I saw that too somewhere, but I couldnt understand how that works.

Comment: edited my question to add a similar thing which confuses me. could you explain that too?

Comment: so, we are actually exporting it from index.js without having to import them? I saw that too somewhere, but I couldnt understand how that works.
so, basically when exporting from index.js I dont need to import those components in the index first??

Comment: @faraz That is just a syntax. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#syntax), this `export A from './A';` part is an invalid way of exporting default despite its import equivalent. The correct way of doing this is to rename the export: `export { default as A } from './A';`.